# Highlight the selected anchor tag in Angularjs (using ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have some data and i have bind the data in `anchor` tag  using ng-repeat

```
<table style="width: 60%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center" ng-repeat="displayyears in displayYears">
                        <div>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding: 30px,30px,30px,30px; font-size: 18px" ng-class="StyleOfYear" ng-click="selectedYear(displayyears,this)">{{displayyears}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

---

**Here is my css code**

```
<style>
    .slectedYear {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .loadYear {
        background-color: none;
    }
</style>
```

---

- Now i want to change the **selected** anchor tag background color. I have tried the below code.

**Js code**

```
//Controller 
 $scope.StyleOfYear = "loadYear";
  $scope.selectedYear = function (value, context) {
            context.$parent.StyleOfYear = "slectedYear";
            $scope.selectedYearValue = value;
        }
```

But am going wrong, because my code  helps to change all anchor tag's background color,  But i want to change the selected anchor tag background color.

---

Now my code is select all anchor tags when i click 2015 
[image]

---

But i want to change the background color of 2015 anchor tag only, if i click 2015. And all other anchor tag's bg-color should be  non.

**look like the below image**

[image]

---

**Simply Am trying to change the  color of active menu concepts, but i  don't know how can i do with `ng-repeat`**

Comment: Can u share your plunker

Comment: Why? it's not a complicated code. You can see my question for what am did.

Comment: I will Put the image

Comment: But i did't get the answer :( @Reena

Comment: ng-class can be a function - make it check if the value of displayyears equals selectedYearValue and return the colour class based on this result.

Comment: @Sam - I think you gave a good key for me.  thanks. i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from @Sam

I have  use a condition with ng-class

**html change**

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding: 30px,30px,30px,30px; 
 font-size: 18px" **ng-class="{slectedYear: displayyears==selectedYearValue}"** 
 ng-click="selectedYear(displayyears,this)">{{displayyears}}</a>
```

**style**

```
<style>
    .slectedYear {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .loadYear {
        background-color: none;
    }
</style>
```

**Js code**

```
$scope.selectedYear = function (value, context) {
            $scope.selectedYearValue = value;
        }
```

Simply i have done with a condition if displaying year equal with selected year then assign the  `slectedYear` class

### Solution:-

This below code solved my problem

```
ng-class="{slectedYear: displayyears==selectedYearValue}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off changing your approach. Use a service for the years, and add a 'selected' attribute to the year object you return.

Then use `ng-repeat` to iterate over those objects and display the colour based on the value of that attribute, for each item in the ng-repeat.

Then your `selectedYear` method can live in the service and simply switch which object has `selected=true` set. The data bindings will take care of the rest.

There are lots of ways to do this depending on you code's syntax and structure, but something like the following could work (untested):

```
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.service('yearService', function(){
    this.years = [
        { 'display': '2012', 'selected': false },
        { 'display': '2013', 'selected': false },
        { 'display': '2014', 'selected': false },
        { 'display': '2015', 'selected': true },
        { 'display': '2016', 'selected': false },
        { 'display': '2017', 'selected': false },
        { 'display': '2018', 'selected': false }
    ];
    this.selectYear = function selectYear(year) {
        // iterate through the years and set only the 
        // selected one to true, others to false
    };
});
```

make sure you inject the service into your controller, and assign it to scope (say, as `yearService`, and

```
<table style="width: 60%">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center" ng-repeat="year in yearService.years">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="year" ng-class="{year.selected: slectedYear}" ng-click="yearService.selectYear(year)">{{year.display}}</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note I've assumed a base CSS class of `.year` instead of the `style` tag, but used your existing `.slectedYear` class.

Your HTML could do with a rewrite too - please get rid of the table!

**EDIT:** I forgot to add the dynamic class - added now.

Comment: Your code looks like  good. but i can't rewrite my year of array (that's coming form backend service . any way my problem was solved

Comment: my vote  for `ng-class="{year.selected: slectedYear}"`

Comment: Thanks for the vote. If it's coming from a server, all the more reason it should be managed from a service. You can easily create the object with the extra property after retrieval. This seems like a lot of overhead but as your project scales it'll be worth it. Anyway, I'm glad you solved your issue.

Comment: Your solution not only requires changes to the data structure, it also requires more logic. You can no longer simply track the selected item but also have to "deselect" the currently selected one. Also keep in mind that if you want to use the selected item anywhere else, you must either track it anyway or iterate through the whole list again to get it.

Comment: @zeroflagL yes that's true. Tracking the selected value as an independent variable is sightly cheaper, but more prone to error over the long term; if this is your pattern you'll end up doing it to something whose value changes dynamically. Is certainly not wing though, but I'd still want that variable on the service so that you can keep track of it across the app...